# Send and Receive Sms from android app through twilio

Tags: android, service, sms

I am newbie to android development.Can anyone please help me.I need to send and receive sms from my app through twilio.When user presses the submit button has to send the password to his mobile number which is filled by the user when he is registering.I dont know where to start.I searched twilio website there are lot of things given.I didnot find the sample code anywhere.So can you guys help me out where I have to begin?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Twilio Evangelist here.

So, it sounds like you're trying to build a Two Factor Authentication system? There is an example of how to do this with [PHP on the Twilio site](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/two-factor-authentication).

You will need a server application as well as the mobile application. When the user submits a form, this will be sent to your server. Then, you can use the [Twilio REST API to send the user an SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms) - there are a lot of [helper libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) you can use too, if you're using Android you may want to use the [Java helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install).

You need to buy a telephone number from Twilio to send the message with, these are form $1/month and available in over 40 countries. You can sign up for free to get started.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way/API using which a native Android app can directly request Twilio to send SMS to a particular(or its own) phone number, from within an Android app?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the Java library (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java) to do this. However, it would mean including your Twilio account credentials in your app, which is probably a bad idea.